# How to use a custom directory for the db in SQLDelight - Android

Tags: android, sqldelight

The default SQLDriver
`AndroidSqliteDriver(OfflinePersonalDataDb.Schema, context, "test.db")` creates the database in a default location:

`/data/data/<Your-Application-Package-Name>/databases/test.db`

can I change this location?

Answer (score 0):

For future readers, the solution is to supply the absolute path to the `name` parameter in the constructor of `AndroidSqliteDriver`:

```
AndroidSqliteDriver(OfflinePersonalDataDb.Schema, context, "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<package>/files/test.db")
```

Here, I am giving a path in the SDCard in the emulator.

Just make sure that your application has the read-write permissions to that location.